# How to add a file extension to a user input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to retrieve a txt doc from server with ajax request.  The name of the txt doc depends on a text input on html doc.  Basically I want to append .txt to the end of the input field following an onclick event

```
// JavaScript Document
function getData(){
    var xmlhttp;
    var user=document.getElementById("nameDetails").value;
    var userText = user + ".txt"; //**not the solution
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
       else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      document.getElementById("userSubmit").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","userText",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Seems to me it should work. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Why does `var userText = user + ".txt";` not work?  If you are just trying to get the input from `nameDetails` and add .txt to it, that should work.  Am I missing something here?  Is `nameDetails` not the textbox that the user puts the filename into?

Comment: It seems like you want `xmlhttp.open("GET",userText,true);` - using the variable instead of passing a string literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append `.txt` to the input field itself, you could try this:

```
document.getElementById("nameDetails").value = document.getElementById("nameDetails").value + ".txt";
```

or the short form:

```
document.getElementById("nameDetails").value += ".txt";
```